# find an item in a list of pointers

Tags: c++, list, find, std

I am trying to understand how to find an item in a list of pointers in C++, using std::find

If I had for example:

```
std::list<string> words;
std::string word_to_be_found;
```

I could just search like this:

```
std::list<string>::iterator matching_iter = std::find(words,begin(), words.end(), word_to_be_found)
```

but what if I have a lsit of pointers?

```
std::list<string *> words;
```

the above syntax will not work anymore. Can I do it some similar way?

thanks!

Answer (score 12):

You can pass a predicate to the `std::find_if` function:

```
bool pointee_is_equal(const std::string& s, const std::string* p) {
    return s == *p;
}

// ...
std::list<string>::iterator matching_iter =
              std::find_if(words,begin(), words.end(),
                          std::bind1st(pointee_is_equal, word_to_be_found));
```

In C++11 this becomes much easier, thanks to lambdas:

```
auto matching_iter = std::find_if(words,begin(), words.end(),
                     [&word_to_be_found](const std::string* p) {
                         return word_to_be_found == *p;
                     });
```

Comment: would something like this work as well? 
`using namespace boost::lambda; `
`find_if(words.begin(), words.end(), *_1 == word_to_be_found);)`

Comment: Yeah, that would work as well (minus the closing parenthesis at the end, of course ;).

Answer (score 4):

Provide your own predicate:

```
struct comparator
{
  bool operator()(std::string const* item)
  {
    return toFind == *item;
  }
  std::string toFind;
};

comparator cinst = { word_to_find };
std::list<string*>::iterator matching_iter = std::find_if(words,begin(), words.end(), cinst)
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [`std::find_if()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/) instead, and supply it a functor to do the comparisons.