# Finding a pointer in a list

Tags: c++, list, pointers, find

I'd like to find an element in a list containing pointers.

This question is quite similar to [find an item in a list of pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778218/find-an-item-in-a-list-of-pointers), but I tried to do it in a different way and it seems to be working.

In the linked question people suggested using find_if, lambdas and thing like this. Isn't it enough to pass the sought pointer to the std::find? Do I miss out something?

Here's the code that I used for testing, and it seems to be working. I run it with different parameters and I got the expected results.

```
typedef struct _C
{
     int num;
     int name;
} C;

int main(void)
{
    C *new_c = new C();
    new_c->num = 2;
    new_c->name = 1;

    C *new_b = new C();
    new_b->num = 3;
    new_b->name = 32;

    C *new_d = new C();
    new_d->num = 1;
    new_d->num = 11;

    std::list<C *> list;
    list.push_front(new_b);
    list.push_front(new_c);

    std::list<C *>::iterator del_new =
        std::find(list.begin(), list.end(), new_c);

    if(del_new != list.end())
        std::cout << "Found" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Not found" << std::endl;
```

Comment: If the pointer is what you're looking for, that's what you should use with `std::find`. The question you linked is concerned with what the pointers point to, not the pointers themselves.

Comment: I don't see the problem here, your code is working, and gets you the expected result, what do you need ?

Comment: I just needed some confirmation on the code that it's okay, and there's nothing wrong with it. As in the linked question people suggested nasty things :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is correct . Looking for a pointer is the same as looking for an integer type, std::find with your list is a good way to look for your pointer (Time complexity o(n)).

Comment: Thanks, I just needed some confirmation :)